# Spring Global ClientInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-ws

I have a legacy application that consumes lots of customer services. Lately, it is required to add a custom http security header per request. One way is to add a ClientInterceptor per WebServiceTemplate but I feel like it is a bit code repeat. Is there a way to apply a global ClientInterceptor ?

As I said this is a legacy system which is still built on top of Spring Fw 3.2.2.RELEASE and spring-ws 2.0.6-RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a general `ClientInterceptor`, something like this:

```java
public class AddCustomSecurityHeader implements ClientInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
       TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
       HttpComponentsConnection connection =(HttpComponentsConnection) context.getConnection();
       connection.addRequestHeader("custom-security-header", "lorem ipsum");

       return true;
    }
}
```

Then you declare a `@Bean` of type `WebServiceTemplate`:

```
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    // add your current configuration here

    ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = {new AddCustomSecurityHeader()};
    webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    return webServiceTemplate;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the comment. Why do you need the WebServiceTemplate injected for interceptor ?

considering that I will use this template for different services; I will have to create different templates with different marshaller/unmarshaller configuration which at some point the same thing that I am trying to not to duplicate config.

Comment: it was a mis-enter :)

Comment: My mistake, I just noticed you need a security header, am I correct to assume it's an Authorization header?

Comment: Correct. it's a custom security header. Not the standart Auth but still an http header. Also your comment light me a bulp :) That I will extend the wstemplate to have the custom interceptor predefined in the empty interceptor list. This should work.

---- edit ----
this goes to an anti pattern and hard to maintain case. I might think to follow standart way I suppose.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, give me a couple of minutes :)

Comment: Done, maybe it's more helpful now :)

Comment: A lot more closer to what I am looking for, yet it is far from my final goal :)
In the end; I will have more than 10 different WsTemplate bean with different marshaller/unmarshaller definitions. which finally the same configuration mess.